# Object required: Error on clicking dynamically generated link in VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and was working on parsing a website using VBA. This website had dynamically generated table elements with pagination.

```
<a onclick="showPage(this.href); return false;" href="/member-finder?p=2" class="paginationLink">Next &gt;</a>
```

After I click on next, previous button comes up in the next page

```
> <a onclick="showPage(this.href); return false;"
> href="/member-finder?p=1" class="paginationLink">&lt; Previous</a>
> 
> <a onclick="showPage(this.href); return false;"
> href="/member-finder?p=3" class="paginationLink">Next &gt;</a>
```

So, to click on this next link, I made the following code in VBA:

```
        Dim focation
        Dim jocation

        If j = 1 Then
            focation = doc.getElementsByClassName("paginationLink")
            focation.Click
            Do
            Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE '= 4
            Sleep 2000
        ElseIf j > 1 And j < TotalPages Then
            jocation = doc.getElementsByClassName("paginationLink")(1)
            jocation.Click
            Sleep 2000
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
        j = j + 1
```

But after the first page, I cannot somehow click on next link as I always have an "Run time error 424: Object required error". I don't know why. If I declare jocation = doc.getElementsByClassName("paginationLink")(0)
the previous link gets clicked. But I want to click on Next link. Tried declaring jocation as IHTMLElement but receive Automation error or unspecified error when I reach 2nd. Is this a problem, because the links are dynamically loaded, but if it works on "previous" link, why not on "next" link . I tried searching here but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Have you tried using `Set jocation = doc.getElementsByClassName("paginationLink")(1)`. VBA likes to strongly define objects.

Comment: perhaps there's an id associated with the `Previous` and `Next` button?

Comment: Yes, tried now. It works. :)

Comment: VBA likes to strongly define objects.